I'm trying to use the downloaded files for kafka, but I'm running into this error VM option 'UseG1GC" is experimental and must be enabled
I'm trying to use the downloaded files for kafka_2.13-3.8.0, but I'm running into this error VM option 'UseG1GC" is experimental and must be enabled via -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions.
Some context:
I'm on a Mac using the m1 chip.
I'm trying to run this command $ KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)" to generate a cluster UUID.
My java version is "1.8.0_421"
Does anyone know what I can do to fix this error?
I tried $ export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC"
and nothing happened.

Please upgrade to Java 21
